# Logging Grizzly Traffic in Mule ESB

Tags: mule, grizzly

I'm having an issue that I think examining the wire traffic might be able to help solve.

But I'm having a couple of problems getting Logging to work:
(This is all in Anypoint Studio March 2015 release)

From the documentation, http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Logging+in+Mule

- Where do I add the Log4j2.xml file for my project? A default one always seems to be used by Mule.
  Near the end of the doc it shows how to make new HTTP connector more verbose, by adding some AsynchLogger elements. But even if I add these manually after the the app has started no extra logging appears in the console window. The documentation says that the configuration files should get reloaded by the Mule after a default 60 seconds, but I'm not sure this is happening.
- Later on in the doc it has a Troubleshooting section, which basically says to add the switch `-M-Dlog4j.debug=true` to show the logging configuration info. But I cannot work out where to use this switch in Anypoint Studio.

Answer (score 0):

1) Add Log4j2.xml to src/main/resources this will be added to the root of your classpath then.

2) The -M is a way of passing arguments to the JVM if you are using the standalone Mule only. In Anypoint Studio you just need to pass -D under Run As -> Run Configurations -> Arguments -> VM Arguments. Not sure if this property works in studio though.

Comment: That's pretty much what I thought, I just couldn't see anything working and was blaming my own Java naivete.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and failed to get wire logging for the Grizzly HTTP client in Mule ESB.  It's probably possible, but I ended up using a workaround.  I installed [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) on my laptop and used an HTTP proxy for the traffic I needed to debug.

Comment: I've failed too...I was trying to view the traffic with Fiddler, but Grizzly wouldn't connect if being pushed to Fiddlers proxy - I might revisit that though as it could just be a small configuration mistake on my part.